# NumberFormatException error while writing a dataframe to HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am writing `dataframe` to `HDFS`, with following code

```
final_df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("path_to_hdfs")
```

and it is giving me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "124085346080"
```

Complete stack below:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "124085346080"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:127)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:258)
    ... 8 more
```

If its trying to convert `"124085346080"` to `int`, I don't see any reason  why it is unable to do that.

Any suggestion on why this is occurring and what can be done to correct it?

Comment: can you provide the schema of your dataframe and sample of your dataframe? And I am assuming the error should not be writing to csv.

Comment: Ramesh: The error is correctly addressed below, and the no mentioned above is out of INT range. As the action happens only while writing the frame, so the error is actually at writing to csv stage.

Comment: Thanks  for letting me know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

124,085,346,080 is way bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is 2,147,483,647), so it can not be converted to an integer. Use a `long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Value `124085346080` cannot be stored in Integer type. Since the maximum value that Integer Can store is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`(2147483647). Try using `long`. change your schema while reading the data to `long`

Comment: As pyspark does not support LongType(), do I have any other option, other than DecimalType() for the same ?

Comment: I think it says it supports LongType() please refer here https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html